# Difference between [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:] and CFDataCreateMutable()?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-foundation, nsmutabledata, cfdata

I'm looking at some code that creates a mutable data object and puts a SHA1 hash into it.  If I initialize the target mutable data object with

```
CFMutableDataRef hashDataRef = (CFMutableDataRef)[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
```

everything works fine.  If I change that one line to

```
CFMutableDataRef hashDataRef = CFDataCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);
```

it breaks (the mutable data object appears to still be empty after the SHA1 command).  In both cases, the line that follows the creation of `hashDataRef` is

```
SHA1(CFDataGetBytePtr(inputDataRef), CFDataGetLength(inputDataRef), CFDataGetMutableBytePtr(hashDataRef));
```

I hadn't expected there to be any difference between the two, but clearly I'm missing something.  Is there a proper Core Foundation way to get the mutable data object I want without using NSMutableData and toll-free bridging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSMutableData initWithLength:` creates a data object whose raw data is filled with zeros, but `CFDataCreateMutable` creates an empty `CFMutableDataRef`. Even though it was created with a capacity, its length is still zero. So, when you use `CFDataGetMutableBytePtr`, it returns a NULL pointer.

To fix it, you could fill the CFMutableDataRef to its capacity using [CFDataSetLength](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableDataRef/Reference/reference.html), which fills the data with zeros.

Comment: Might be worth noting that `CFDataCreateMutable()` is more similar to `-[NSMutableData initWithCapacity:]`.

Comment: Actually, that similarity is misleading. The capacity of `CFDataCreateMutable()` is a strict limit. The "capacity" of `-[NSMutableData initWithCapacity:]` is just a lower bound of the *first* allocation (when that happens), but does not prevent the object from being grown beyond that. It's mostly just an optimization.